# "To arrive at school" and "at school to arrive"

Tags: prepositions

I work at an ESL school and my students were taking an exam that asked them to unscramble words into a sentence. The result (as given by the answer key) was:

> Jessica was the last person to arrive at school.

However, one of my students wrote the sentence:

> Jessica was the last person at school to arrive.

I told my co-teacher that I thought this construction was also correct and that the student should get credit for his answer. Is the second sentence also correct?

Comment: Your second version is syntactically correct, but doesn't mean the same as the first. It means that of all the people who arrived (anywhere, not necessarily a school) Jessica was the last one who was actually "at school" (i.e. - a ***schoolgirl***). Others who might have arrived later than Jessica weren't schoolchildren. As is normal in English, adverbial elements such as ***at school*** apply by default to the immediately-preceding noun or verb.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The task was simply to form a correct sentence, so I wasn't too worried about intention or meaning.

Comment: Each question must be judged on its merits, but most likely anything else you want to ask would be better posted on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (to where I have voted to migrate this question).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have a slight problem with this.  Whatever the adverb phrase ‘at school’ modifies, it is surely not the verb ‘was’, but the the noun ‘person’.  It would be equivalent to “...was the last person <of those> at school...”.   Wouldn’t  it in any case a rather odd way to put it?  You might say “... last person IN THE SCHOOL to arrive”.

Comment: @Tuffy: Hmm. How would you contrive a context where *Jessica was at school the last person to arrive* might be credible? I'd say that *could* make sense if we suppose we're being told that *back when she was at school*, Jessica was [habitually] the last person to arrive [every morning, perhaps]. And it seems to me that adverbial "at school" *would* be modifying ***was*** in that construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I must have misunderstood you or expressed myself badly.  I think that ‘at school’ is meant to modify the verb ‘arrive’ and is misplaced; or rather is not where such an adverb phrase would normally be.  I thought you were taking the possibility that ‘at school’ would be in the sense of ‘pupil at <the> school, where ‘at the school’ meant the same as ‘of the school’ (which it could, though Personally I think it unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatical.

---

So, too, are these additional sentences formed from the same words (assuming that meaning doesn't matter and that punctuation and grammar isn't forced):

> The last person to arrive at school was Jessica.
>   The last person at school to arrive was Jessica.
>   At school was Jessica, the last person to arrive.
>   At school, the last person to arrive was Jessica.
>   Was Jessica the last person to arrive at school?
>   Was Jessica, the last person to arrive, at school?
>   Was the last person to arrive at school Jessica?

Other grammatical sentences could be formed, but they might be nonsensical.